# How to convert time in bash

Tags: bash, shell, time

I have variable (for example `someDate`) which hold time in format `YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS` (for example `2017/06/26 00:00:00`) and now I want to add to this variable +3 days.

But when I'm doing

```
newDate=$(date -d "$someDate + 3 days")
```

I get always only

```
Mon Jun 26 23:00:00 CEST 2017
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to remove `+` from command, `date -d "2017/06/26 00:00:00 3 days"` worked well for me. [Documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Relative-items-in-date-strings.html#Relative-items-in-date-strings)